# How to display a specific post type name in a breadcrumb

Tags: custom-post-types

I have this function:

```
function the_breadcrumb() {
    if (!is_home()) {
        echo "Start » ";
        echo '<a href="';
        echo get_option('home');
        echo '">';
        bloginfo('name');
        echo "</a> » ";
        if (is_category() || is_single() ) {
        the_category('title_li=');
        if (is_single()) {
            echo " » ";
            the_title();
        }
    } elseif (is_page()) {
        echo the_title();
    } elseif (is_single() && $post_type == 'partners') {
        echo "IS THIS WORKING?";
            }
    } elseif (is_home()) {
    echo "Start » ";    bloginfo('name');
    }
}
```

I also have created a custo post type called 'partners'.

However, my breadcumb does not display my IS THIS WORKING TEXT

Help appreciated.
Alex

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic failure to indent code leading to confusion issue.

If we reformat your code correctly we see:

```
function the_breadcrumb() {
    if (!is_home()) {
        echo "Start » ";
        echo '<a href="';
        echo get_option('home');
        echo '">';
        bloginfo('name');
        echo "</a> » ";
        if (is_category() || is_single() ) {
            the_category('title_li=');
            if (is_single()) {
                echo " » ";
                the_title();
            }
        } elseif (is_page()) {
            echo the_title();
        } elseif (is_single() && $post_type == 'partners') {
            echo "IS THIS WORKING?";
        }
    } elseif (is_home()) {
        echo "Start » ";    bloginfo('name');
    }
}
```

Now we can follow it appropriately. What's happening is it's entering the `is_category || is_single()` if statement, and executing that part first. Because the if statement succeeded, it never reaches your check later on.

But, even if it did, there's a second problem, you're checking `$post_type`, but where is this coming from? Nowhere is it declared as a global or assigned a value, *it's been plucked out of thin air*.

So here is my alternative:

```
function the_breadcrumb() {
    if (is_home()) {
        echo "Start » ";
        bloginfo('name');
        return;
    }
    echo "Start » ";
    echo '<a href="'.home_url().'">';
    bloginfo('name');
    echo "</a> » ";

    // Check each case starting with the most specific down to the most generic
    global $post;
    $post_type = '';
    if ( !empty( $post) {
        $post_type = $post->post_type;
    }
    if ( is_single() && $post_type == 'partners' ) {
        echo "IS THIS WORKING?";
    } elseif ( is_page() ) {
        echo the_title();
    } else if (is_category() || is_single() ) {
        the_category('title_li=');
        if (is_single()) {
            echo " » ";
            the_title();
        }
    }
}
```

Here I've used the global post object to get around the lack of a `$post_type` variable to compare against. I've also re-ordered the if statements from most specific to most generic. Finally I took the big if else on the `is_home` call and put it at the top and did a return, that way we don't nest the code as much and it becomes more readable, and a comment for good measure. I also used `home_url` instead of `get_option('home')`

So in summary:

- Always indent correctly. ***You have no excuses for not doing it***, most editors will do this for you. If yours doesn't, go grab sublimetext or another IDE like Komodo or PHPStorm.
- Read your code from top to bottom and follow it in your head. It's not hard and bugs like this become quite obvious very quickly. It also gets far far easier as you do it, eventually you won't need to think about it at all, it'll just happen automatically
- Never put » in html, always use the entitycode else your html won't validate

Comment: @Tom, thank you for the lecture :) Believe or not, I am trying to keep things organized but I can never learn how to paste the code in here to make it look like in my editor :(

Comment: Right now I'm getting a `Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_post_type() in ...` - I registered the post type like this: `register_post_type( 'partners',
    array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'supports' => $supports
    )` - but, maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Maybe because you're mixing tabs and spaces? I've changed the is_post_type to a call to the global post object, is_post_type didnt do what I thought it did

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tom J Nowell's answer...

You haven't set `$post_type` anywhere. That condition will always fail, and if you enabled [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) you'd probably see some notices about it.

I don't know how to fix that as the code is out of context and I don't if, where, or how you've set `$post_type`. If you defined it as `global` somewhere then `global $post_type;` at the head of the function should do it. Maybe you need...

```
global $post;
$post_type = $post->post_type;
```

... but that could be problematic for some pages, like archive pages.n

Sorry, best I can do given the information.

Comment: Thank you @s_ha_dum - I registered post_type previously like this: 'register_post_type( 'partners',
    array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'supports' => $supports
    )' makes sense?